# Java - IndexOutOfBoundsException in getting the highest integer

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to create a score system and get the best score but my method generates a IndexOutOfBoundsException but I can't find whats out of the arraylist bounds can someone help me?

code:

```
 public static Player getBestScore(Arena arena) {
    System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().size());
    System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().get(1).toString());
    int i = 0;
    Player player = null;
    for(int p = 0; p != arena.getAPlayers().size() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().get(i).toString());
        org.bukkit.entity.Player pla = arena.players.get(i);
        if(getArenaPlayer(pla).getScore() > i) {
            i = getArenaPlayer(pla).getScore();
            player = getArenaPlayer(pla);
        }
    }
    return player;
}
```

The method is static because other methods and variables are static too

Comment: Lists start their index at 0 like other array-like structures. This line `System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().get(1).toString());` could be problematic if there is only 1 player.

Comment: your for loop condition should be like for(int i=0; i < arean.getAplayer().size(); i++) and then try

Comment: @BrettWalker it cant because the minium of the score systen arraylist is 2

Comment: @DannSander, not exactly obvious from this small code sample. Nor stated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `i` and `p` wrongly!
In the loop, you set `i` to a certain high score, which is likely larger than the size of the array, and hence the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public static Player getBestScore(Arena arena) {
    System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().size());
    System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().get(1).toString());
    int i = 0;
    Player player = null;

    // index of for loop is p
    for(int p = 0; p != arena.getAPlayers().size() - 1; i++) {

        System.out.println(arena.getAPlayers().get(p).toString());
        org.bukkit.entity.Player pla = arena.players.get(p);

        // If player's score is higher than current highscore(i)
        if(getArenaPlayer(pla).getScore() > i) {

            // Set current highscore(i) to this player's score
            i = getArenaPlayer(pla).getScore();
            player = getArenaPlayer(pla);
        }
    }
    return player;
}
```

Which is why you should name your variables in a better way!
Using `highscore` instead of `i`, and possibly `index` instead of `p` would have made it a lot less confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- you don't need to declare `i` outside the loop
- you don't need `p` variable
- you souldn't use `!=` to check a `for-loop` (usually)

This:

```
for(int p = 0; p != arena.getAPlayers().size() - 1; i++) {
//      ^      ^                                    ^ different
//               ^ != WROOOONG!!!
```

is not a good for-loop definition. To avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException` use it in this way

```
for(int i = 0; i < arena.getAPlayers().size(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for(int p = 0; p < arena.getAPlayers().size(); p++) {
```

instead of

```
for(int p = 0; p != arena.getAPlayers().size() - 1; i++) {
```